# Modifying volume in a chrome tab with tabs API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to make a chrome extension that allows you to control the volume of multiple tabs. I need a way to increase/decrease volume per tab but looking at the tabs API there is only a muted method. Is there a way of doing this through Google's API?
Is there another way of accomplishing this with other methods?

Comment: Tabs don't have volume controls. A tab (page) can have multiple audio sources and each of those sources has an independent volume control. Note that mute and volume control are not the same thing.

Comment: Its just that there is an extension that does this already but it only has 1 slider for the current audio source/tab (im assuming that in most cases a tab will only have 1 audio source) but I want to have a slider for each source to control on the extension itself, without having to switch tabs manually and opening the extension again

Comment: I don't think it's possible with just Google's API.

Comment: Should be able to unpack that extension to at least see how they did it.